# SVN best-practices - working in a team

Tags: svn

I'm starting out with SVN.  I know the basic commands and understand the base principles.  I was wondering if anyone has any tips or best practices for working with Subversion in a team environment.

I can see the benefit of adding reasonably verbose messages when committing code, but are there other things I should bear in mind?

**Thanks for all the great answers - they've helped a lot.**

Answer (score 77):

**Encourage frequent commits.**  Teammates new to version control may feel like they need to keep the code out of the repository until "it works right".  Teach everyone to commit early and often to find issues as soon as possible.  Instead of holding code 'till it works, propose that your teammates create branches for feature that might break trunk.  That leads to...

**Establish a branching and tagging practice.**  In addition to branches for features, encourage your teammates to use branches for large-bug fixes.  Tag major bug fixes at the beginning and end of the work.  Maintain tags (and possibly branches) for production/qa releases.

**Establish a policy for trunk and stick to it.**  One example might be, "trunk must always build without errors." or "trunk must always pass all unit tests".  Any work that can't yet meet the standards of trunk must be done in a branch.

Comment: branching and merging is something of a pain in SVN. Other VCSs handle it much better, but I would never advocate a branch-heavy process for SVN.

Comment: @Branan WRONG. it's because you don't know how to use source control properly.  When you branch, you are expected as a good dev to do your job and to UPDATE your branch from trunk and merge latest changes from trunk to your branch DAILY or several times a day (your choice) so that in the end you don't have merge hell that has piled up.  I have at least 4-5 branches going on all the time locally on my PC and it's NEVER this nightmare people speak of because I'm doing it right...updating it often so that I have the changes people are checking into trunk and working and adding code in relation to

Answer (score 67):

**Do not commit formatting changes with code changes**

If you want to restructure a giant file's whitespace (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), fine.  Commit the formatting change separately from the actual logical change.  Same goes if you want to move functions around in files.  Commit the moving separately from the actual editing.

Comment: so i edit a file all day, and now its time to commit it, how do i separate out the formatting?

Comment: If you're going to do formatting changes with existing code, do it first, commit, then add the new code/edit the code. Or add/edit first, commit, then do the formatting change. This way the diff on the add/edit actually makes sense and doesn't simply say "everything is different now!'.

Comment: +1. Extraneous changes increase the effort that it takes to review the pertinent changes. Also makes it harder to merge/port changes (to say, a different branch).

Comment: While this is a good practice to follow, I don't think anyone's going to be able to possibly enforce this. Jason is right, that a good developer will realize they can ignore whitespaces with a good diff tool (one is built into tortoise SVN) to filter out the noise.

Comment: This can be enforced via code reviews and education to team members. I don't think it should be the burden of the reviewer to separate the logical changes from the code changes. It should be the responsibility of the implementer.

Answer (score 44):

One of the key concepts I always stick by is to **commit related code changes together**.  The corollary is **do not commit unrelated code changes in the same commit**.  This means don't fix 2 bugs in one commit (unless it's the same fix), and don't commit half a bug fix in each of 2 commits.  Also, if I need to add some new enhancement or something to an unrelated part of the system that I then need for some other work, I commit the enhancement separately (and first).  The idea is that any change anyone might conceivably want to have on its own (or roll back on its own) should be a separate commit.  It will save you tons of headaches when it comes time to do merges or to roll back broken features.

Comment: +1 to this.  It seems like such a pain when you're committing.  But a repo full of atomic commits is priceless when you're reviewing old code.

Comment: isn't that what a feature branch is for ... do as many commits as needed, on the feature branch, then when you are ready merge it to trunk ... rollbacks only mean removing the merged commit. +1 for keeping related code together ...

Answer (score 18):

A lot has been mentioned already, and here are some more:

1. If you have files that you don't want in source control (e.g. configuration, compiled files, etc.), add them to the **ignore list**.  This way you notice any files that you forget to add by always expecting an empty list of files showing as unknown to SVN.
2. Add a **post commit event that would send an email to your developer mailing list** (or a one specific for this target) relating to the committed change and ideally the patch for it.
3. **Integrate with your bug tracker** so that references to commits show up on the bugs / feature requests with links to the diffs. Bug trackers like [MantisBT](http://www.mantisbt.org) support this.
4. Consider integrating with **continuous integration** (e.g. [CruiseControl.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet)), [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) for Build, and [NUnit](http://nunit.org/)/VS for unit tests. This way once a user check-ins code or on a scheduled interval the code gets compiled, unit tests are run, and the developer gets feedback of the process. This would also alert the rest of the team if the repository is broken (i.e. doesn't build).

Comment: practice we use is that all configuration files have changed extension like config.php.config or something like that this way we keep our config files on server, but every team member has its own. When something big changes in config file than we make copy form svn version...

Answer (score 15):

Well, the basics:

- Create tags before starting QA on a version
- Create tags before risky changes (i.e. big refactors)
- Create branches for released versions in order to freeze the code.
- Make sure that people know to update before starting work on a piece of code and update once again before committing it.
- SVN allows multiple check outs of the same file by different users. Make sure that everyone resolves any conflict that may occur.
- **Never** use the same SVN account for more than one user. Terrible things may result.

Comment: I do the opposite with my branches and tags. Branches are for forks from the trunk, which eventually get merged with trunk. Tags are for code freezes.

Comment: Branches are copies that can change.

Tags are copies that should NOT change.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

Comment: I do a similar thing.  I tag and branch when I release code to QA or production.  This way we have a read-only marker as well as a branch to address bug fixes for that release that won't impact new feature development that may take place on the trunk.

Comment: Svn allows also multiple checkouts of the same folder for the same user. So if you find that you need to make a change that is unrelated to your current work (i.e. some customer calling for an emergency fix or you find a completely unrelated bug by chance) checkout again and fix it separately.

Comment: "tags" should be used for code freezes. If you try to change the "tag" branch, your SVN client even warns you.

Answer (score 12):

The answers that people are giving are great.  Much of this is summarized in the svn user doc for [best practices for SVN](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html).
To repeat:

1. Set up your repository structure (you should have project root with trunk, branches, and tags underneath)
2. Choose your policy re branching (private branches,
   branches per milestone/release/bug,
   etc) and stick to it -- I'd
   recommend more branching rather than
   less, but no need for private
   branches
3. Choose your policy re
   tagging -- more tags the better, but
   most importantly decide on your tag
   naming conventions
4. Choose your
   policy re committing to trunk --
   keep trunk as "clean" as possible,
   it should be release-able at any
   time

Comment: That is a pretty old best practice, so I don't think that CollabNet recommends them any more. Is there any new best practices available? The one you mentioned goes back to SVN 1.0

Comment: @mliebelt - I updated the link to the apache version.  Regardless of age the ideas of choosing your repo structure, your branching policies, your tagging policies and your trunk commit policies, along with the really good answers above, are still sound.

Comment: That "Branch-When-Needed system" description is pretty nuts though. Sounds like a recipe for an office shooting.

Answer (score 12):

I would like to summarize best practices I stick to:

1. **Do not commit binaries**. There should be separate repository for binaries, such as *Nexus*, *Ivy* or *Artifactory*.
2. There should be **repository structure**. Personally I use following repository structure:

   ```
   /trunk
   /tags
       /builds
           /PA
           /A
           /B
       /releases
           /AR
           /BR
           /RC
           /ST
   /branches
       /experimental
       /maintenance
           /versions
           /platforms
       /releases
   ```
3. Use specific list of **branch types**. My list is following: *experimental*, *maintenance*, *versions*, *platforms*, *releases*.
4. Use specific **types of tags**: `PA` (pre-alpha), `A` (alpha), `B` (beta), `AR` (alpha-release), `BR` (beta-release), `RC` (release candidate), `ST` (stable).
5. **Minimize necessity of merging**. There should be rules when merging is possible/encouraged and when it is not.
6. **Version numbering**. There should be established version numbering approach to stick to. Usually it is described in such document as Software Configuration Management Plan, it is a part of high-level project documentation. Personally I use complex version numbering approach. According to this approach, versions have following patterns: **N.x.x** (maintenance/support branches), **N.M.x** (release branch), **N.x.K** (build), **N.M.K** (release).
7. **Commit as frequent as possible**. If it tends to be difficult (for example, when there should be too many changes to be made in order to implement feature and even compile code), experimental branches should be used.
8. **Trunk should contain the latest development**. For example, when there is a choice where to develop new major version (**N.x.x**) of application, in *trunk* or in branch, decision should be always made in favor of *trunk*. The old version should be branched into the *maintenance/support* branch. It assumes that there is a clear distinction between major versions and their specifics (architecture, compatibility) emerges *as early as possible*.
9. **Strict 'do not break the build' policy on release branches**. In the meantime, it should not necessarily be strict for *trunk* as long as it might have either experimental development or codebase which needs merge issues to be resolved.
10. Use **svn:externals**. It will allow to modularize your project, establish transparent release management procedure, divide and conquer over different functionality.
11. Use **issue tracking**. You will be able to point out the issue reference inside the commit message.
12. **Disable empty commit messages**. It could be done using pre-commit hooks.
13. Define **which branches you want to continuously integrate**. For example I prefer using continuous integration for *trunk*, *maintenance* and *release* branches.
14. Establish **continuous integration policy** for different types of branches. As I pointed out earlier, most strict "don't break the build" rules apply to *release* branches, while *trunk* and *maintenance* branches might be broken sometimes. Also there is difference between list of inspections run on the *trunk/maintenance* and *release* branches.

You can find outline of my subversion best practices in the form of [diagram](http://scm.altern.kiev.ua/images/branches_naming_A3.en.jpg) illustrating main principles of software configuration management approach I use.

Comment: So, ho do you work in team? Do different people use different branches? How to avoid conflicts? You answer doesn't cover teamwork :(

Comment: Q: **How to avoid conflicts?** A: *Minimize necessity of merging*, *Trunk should contain the latest development*, *Commit as frequent as possible*
Q: **Do different people use different branches?** A: *Each branch can be used by one or more people. It is also important to distinct branches types: experimental, maintenance and release, it helps to avoid conflicts*
Q: **You answer doesn't cover teamwork** A: *It might seem from the first glance. Using version control automatically means teamwork. I described the set of rules (as rules of the road) which help to collaborate even more effectively*

Comment: I'm new to SVN, i know this is an old question, but still i have one question in 2021. Why having release branches when you have Trunk and tags which also may have releases? is it really necessary to have a release branch (or more than one?). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioAvendañoHuergo: release branches are there to isolate ongoing development in, for example, trunk (that most likely will contain feature commits) from the effort of stabilizing a release with bugfixes without accepting such major changes as feature commits

Answer (score 7):

One thing I've found very useful is the [svn:external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) property which means you can reference directories from other repositories into your own. It's gives really nice ways of organizing your code and data. Some examples are:

1. If you have a separate repositories for code different modules/libraries and reference in the ones you are using. This means that you can have a meta repository for every executable. If it's a small executable that only uses a few modules, you won't need to checkout the entire tree. An effect of this is that you get SVN revision numbers per module.
2. Adding large binary data such as compiled versions of libraries to code repository is generally considered a bad habit, but it can be really convenient. If you just add all versions of all libraries you use to a different repository you can get the best of two worlds. You reference in the versions of the libraries you use into your code repository. When checking out your code repository you'll get both the code and the binaries as well. However the binaries are stored in a large repository which you don't need to backup as rigorously as your source code and the source code repository stays small and contains only text.

Comment: I like point 2. Since you can specify a revision number or not when using svn:external, this will let you "pin" some libraries to specific versions while allowing others to "track" the latest version.

Comment: Using "svn:external"s is one of the most powerfull, and I would say most basic features of SVN. It's a must.

Answer (score 5):

Use integration with your bug tracking software. If you use [Bugzilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla), you can set it up so if your comment begins with "Bug XXXX" your SVN comment is automatically added as a comment to the given bug, including a link to you SVN web interface to that revision.

Comment: Trac has good svn integration for bug tracking, plus timeline, commit diffs, wiki, etc.

Comment: Jira also tracks commits related to the issues

Answer (score 4):

Learn about SVN's branching and merging tools and conventions.

The best way to work with other team members is to break work up into complete development features/fixes, then work on individual changes, each in a branch.  Then merge the changes back to the mainline branch/trunk when completed/ready/approved to be merged in.

This way individuals can work towards a common goal (either on the same branch or seperate branches) without colliding with other changes.

Your mileage may vary, and this may be overkill for only two or so people.

Answer (score 4):

The golden rule for source control: **Check In Early, Check In Often**

For tips how to organize your repository:

- *[How do you organize your version control repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222827/how-do-you-organize-your-version-control-repository)*
- [SVN Book Chapter 5. Repository Administration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout)
- [Repository layout](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/04/subversion_repo.html)

Answer (score 3):

It makes it much easier if you're using good tools that integrate well with SVN. These make it easy to see what's been changed and to then commit all or part of your changes and to frequently update your working copy to the latest version in SVN.

I recommend [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (If you're using Windows) and [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) (if you're using VS).

Also see if you can set it up so that you get e-mail or similar notification any time a change is committed (usually also including the commit message and a list of changed files). Services like [CVSDude](http://cvsdude.com/) offer this. I find it helpful to know both that an update has been made and then to have some idea of what's contained in that update before updating my working copy.

Answer (score 3):

Besides branching policies et al. (where one size does definitely not fit all), you should have good commits:

- The commit should relate to a *single* piece of work if possible; a bug fix, a new feature- there should be some 'logic' to what changes you committed
- The commit should have a descriptive comment that will help you locate it browsing the repository history. Most people suggest writing a single sentence at the beginning that describes the whole commit and a more detailed account below
- If possible, you should tie the commit to your bug-tracking system if possible. Trac, Redmine et al. let you create links from bugs to commits and vice versa, which comes in very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Consult with your team about their changes, or at least look at the diff very carefully,  before fixing any merge conflicts.  Ask them to review the merged code themselves to make sure their additions were not lost in the merge.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I have seen that reduces broken commits is to have good pre-commit scripts. For example, you can run any unit tests before the change is committed. This will cause commits to be a little slow, but you save time by avoiding stepping on someone's toes and having to apologize. Of course this becomes a lot harder to manage when you have a large development team and very frequent commits.

Comment: +1 for pre-commit scripts. Great idea. I wonder if there's a way to get git to give you a smack over the hand if you try committing without running it?

Answer (score 2):

One of the examples of integration with bug-tracker and commit policy enforcing could be [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)'s svn pre/post-commit hook scripts, which can refuse commit if commit message doesn't reference any ticket in bug-tracker and add comments to existing tickets based on message contents (i.e. commit message may contain something like "Fixes #1, #2 and #8", where #1, #2, #8 are the tickets numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Best practice to use [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion):

1. When you first came to office and open your [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) project, the first step has to be done is to update your project.
2. After taking update, start your work. When you finished your coding, check it properly, whether your application runs properly without any exception. Once you are sure about your code is working fine, it's time to commit the code.

Note :While committing the code, don’t commit directly. Make a synchronization with server and check what are all needs to be committed.
Note: Don’t commit the whole folder once. Because you may have done some changes to file for your requirement or you may have deleted some files in your local system. But the settings are different on the server. So check the files individually and commit the code.

3. Don’t commit/update conflict files directly.
4. When to do override and update?

   When you are pretty much sure that you don’t need any of your local
   changes and want to update the server copy completely. Note down that
   once if you do the override and update, you will not get any of your
   local changes.

   Note: Don’t keep the project without updating for more than a day. Also don’t keep the code without committing for many days.
5. Communicate who are all working in same component and discuss what changes they have made every day.
6. Don’t commit the properties and configuration file unless there is some reason. Because the settings will be different on a server and in the cloud.
7. Don’t commit target folders into SVN, only source code and resource folders has to be maintained in an SVN repository.
8. When you lost your code, don’t panic! You can get back the earlier copy from the SVN history.
9. Don’t checkout the project into multiple places of your disk. Checkout it in one location and work with it.

---

Answer (score 1):

SVN by itself is a good start and some of the other posters have offered some great suggestions on best practices.

The only thing I would add is that you should be hooking up SVN with CruiseControl or TeamCity to drive a Continuous Integration process.  This will send out build emails and let everyone know when someone broke the build.

It will be very telling early on who's following your process and who isn't.  Might lead to some friction but your team will be better off in the long run.

Comment: agreed, CruiseControl has saved my team numerous times.

Answer (score 1):

- Precise comment for every commit
- Don’t break the (mainline) build!
- Commit as soon as a logical unit changes
- Avoid using Subversion as a backup tool
- A little branching/merging as possible

.

More details can be found in *[SVN best practices](https://ducquoc.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/svn-best-practices/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the comments template:

[task / story xxx][minor / major][comment][follow up comment][URL to bug]

Answer (score 0):

### Do DEV work on Branches

1. Frequent commits to your branch
2. Discrete/Modular commits to your branch *([see here](http://sarah.thesharps.us/2013/05/08/patchsets-for-dinner/))*
3. Update/Merge-from trunk often. Don't *sit* on your branch without re-basing

### Community Trunk

1. Should always build/work
2. One issue per commit *([again see here](http://sarah.thesharps.us/2013/05/08/patchsets-for-dinner/))* Mostly so you or others can back-things-out one at a time
3. **Don't** conflate refactoring/whitespace changes with logical changes.  Your teammates will have a tough time extracting what you *actually did* from a commit

Remember that the more incremental, modular, discrete and succinct you make your commits, the easier it will be for you (or likely others) to:

- Incrementally back out changes
- Visually realize what you actually did without sifting through tons of white space and variable name changes.
- The commit messages mean more when the ratio of work done to message length is lower.