# SVN build revision

Tags: svn, version-control, build

We are working on a java project and have an automatic build everyday, and most of the times we would have checked in our code even though it is not complete just to save it, many times the build breaks due to a single person (not due to error, just that his code is incomplete).

To avoid this is there any option in SVN that I can assign a build revision/tag so that it takes files from this revision, i.e people who have completed the code will have their build revision as the latest revision and people who have incomplete code checkin will point their build revision to an earlier revision so as not to break the build.

Comment: it's called 'svn cp'.

Comment: @bmargulies isn't that just a local copy of some svn revision?

Comment: svn cp is how you make a tag in subversion. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Branch-when-needed as explained in [Subversion best practices doc](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html) is probably the best approach to take.

```
The Branch-When-Needed system
    Users commit their day-to-day work on /trunk.
    Rule #1: /trunk must compile and pass regression tests at all times. Committers who violate this rule are publically humiliated.
    Rule #2: a single commit (changeset) must not be so large so as to discourage peer-review.
    Rule #3: if rules #1 and #2 come into conflict (i.e. it's impossible to make a series of small commits without disrupting the trunk), then the user should create a branch and commit a series of smaller changesets there. This allows peer-review without disrupting the stability of /trunk.

Pros: /trunk is guaranteed to be stable at all times. The hassle of branching/merging is somewhat rare.
Cons: Adds a bit of burden to users' daily work: they must compile and test before every commit.
```

Use `svn copy (cp)` to create branches to manage non-trivial changes.

```
svn copy <base url or path>/trunk <base url or path>/branches/enhancement-1
```

Then commit changes related to those changes into the branch, but not to trunk.
Merge changes from trunk to those branches, regularly, in order to not outdate branch from trunk.

```
cd branch-dir
svn merge -r <rev1>:<rev2> <base url or path>/trunk
svn ci
```

When changes in branch are stable enough, merge them back to trunk.

```
cd trunk-dir
svn merge -r <revX>:<revY> <base url or path>/branches/enhancement-1
svn ci
```

**Keeping track of important revision numbers (rev1, rev2, revX, revY, etc.) will make it lot easier than going through `svn log`.**

Sample repository layout.

```
project/
├── branches
│   ├── major-refactoring-1     <= specific changes on a refactoring that can not be moved to trunk yet
│   ├── production              <= most of the time changes from trunk will be merged into this for production releases
│   ├── user-1                  <= certain changes done by a user not stable enough to move to trunk
│   └── user-2
├── tags
└── trunk
```

Other Guides:
http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=623
[SVN best-practices - working in a team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417599/svn-best-practices-working-in-a-team)

Comment: You should use _sync merge_ to merge changes from trunk to branch (i.e. without revision arguments) and _reintegrate merge_ to reintegrate the feature branch into trunk (i.e. with the option `--reintegrate`).

Comment: @nosid Good point. I haven't used both options (sync/reintegrate) before but will give them a try.