# Managing a build all solution in TFS

Tags: tfs

I'm the TFS admin at my company.  In the past, I have recommended a linear branching strategy for small teams that are also new to TFS.  Start in Dev > Dev merge up to Test > Test merge up to Prod.

This works well with solutions whose projects are subdirectories of the solution.  What about projects that are dispersed throughout source control?

Can I create a single branch that that can manage projects dispersed in various locations in source control?

> E.G.
>
> \$TFS\Dev\Project1 
>   \$TFS\Dev\SomeFolder\Project2
>   \$TFS\Dev\SomeOtherFolder\Project3

We have a main project that houses all our Assemblies.  This project is the "build all" project.  It is used with finalBuilder pro to perform the deployment to the next tier.  The issue is that these projects are spread out all over source control.  I'm not sure how to manage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With Team Build, not only you can build solutions across branches, you can build solutions across different team projects. However, I think the best practice is keeping each project and each branch with their own build definition.

In your case, I'd first try to [organize the source tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222827/147211), then define a master solution that builds all projects. FinalBuilder should support your scenario, though I think FinalBuilder is redundant when you have TFS.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to identify which "projects" are released and versioned independently, and have separate branching structures for each of those.

You don't want to have 2 independent projects (by independent I mean they are released/versioned separately) within the same branching structure.

The typical way to manage dependencies between these projects is to checkin the binaries from Project 1 Version X into the Project 2 "lib" folder.  That way you can release new versions of Project 1 at will, but the Project 2 team can decide when and if to take a dependency on the new version.

If your various "projects" are all pieces of the one big thing that is released/versioned together, then I'd recommend just making sure they all live under some root folder (e.g. $\TFS\Dev) and branch from there.