# Subversion svn:externals - What's wrong here?

Tags: svn, version-control, shared-objects, svn-externals, file-organization

I first want to say I've read the Subversion manual. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222827/how-do-you-organize-your-version-control-repository). I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217/how-would-you-organize-a-subversion-repository-for-in-house-software-projects). Here's my dilemma.

Let's say I have 3 repositories laid out like this:

- DataAccessObject/

  - branches/
  - tags/
  - trunk/

    - DataAccessObject/
    - DataAccessObjectTests/
- PlanObject/

  - branches/
  - tags/
  - trunk/

    - PlanObject/
    - PlanObjectTests/
- WinFormsPlanViewer/

  - branches/
  - tags/
  - trunk/

    - WinFormsPlanViewer/

The PlanObject and DataAccessObject repositories contain shared projects. They are used by the WinFormsPlanViewer, but also by several other projects in several other repositories.

Bear with me here. I put an svn:externals definition on the WinFormsPlanViewer/trunk folder like this:

```
https://server/svn/PlanObject/trunk Objects<br/>
https://server/svn/DataAccessObject/trunk Objects<br/>
```

And here's what I see after I do an svn update.

- WinFormsPlanViewer/

  - branches/
  - tags/
  - trunk/

    - WinFormsPlanViewer/
    - Objects/

      - DataAccessObject/
      - DataAccessObjectTests/

The PlanObject stuff doesn't even come down in the update! I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but there's an externals definition on the PlanObject/trunk folder also:

```
https://server/svn/DataAccessObject/trunk Objects<br/>
```

What's going on here? What am I doing wrong? Are there bad consequences of referencing the PlanObject and the DataAccessObject from the WinFormsPlanViewer using svn:externals when the PlanObject references the DataAccessObject using svn:externals also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have configured the svn:externals property to populate the Objects directory with the contents of two different URLs. Try creating the two svn:externals with different directory names:

```
https://server/svn/PlanObject/trunk PlanObjects
https://server/svn/DataAccessObject/trunk DataAccessObjects
```

Comment: If I do this, then I have a copy of DataAccessObject inside the WinFormsPlanViewer/trunk/WinFormsPlanViewer/PlanObject directory, and then also inside the WinFormsPlanViewer/trunk directory. The PlanObject would reference the DataAccessObject inside the PlanObject directory, and the WinformsPlanViewer would reference the one inside the trunk directory. Right? Not what I'm looking for...

Comment: You're right, Billie. Can't have multiple externals with the same target folder. (See my answer for how I solved the problem in the comment above)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, just thought of this this morning and wanted to kicked myself because I didn't think of it before. I'm going to define my svn:externals like this:

> https://server/svn/PlanObject/trunk/PlanObject Objects/PlanObject
>   https://server/svn/DataAccessObject/trunk/DataAccessObject Objects/DataAccessObject

I'm marking Billie's answer as accepted because he did answer my question about why the svn:externals definition wasn't working.