# Which Eclipse Subversion plugin should I use?

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/), or [something else](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=svn+eclipse&spell=1)?

There's a bit of [debate](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=subclipse+vs+subversive&btnG=Google+Search&meta=) around the topic, can we come to some conclusion here?

**EDIT:**
It's been a couple months now, and I ended up deciding the plugin slowed Eclipse down too much, and was a hassle to use every time I changed a file from outside Eclipse.
I ditched the plugin all together and just went with TortiseSVN.

Comment: I notice there's also this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive

Comment: Thanks.
funny that searching "Eclipse Subversion" and "Eclipse svn" don't bring this result up on the first page. Also, while typing the question title this dupe didn't show up there either. I assume they're working on that.

Comment: I am writing this some 7 years later.. and it seems Subversive is no longer supported on latest releases (on STS 4 based on  Eclipse 4.13 (Help -> About Spring Tool Suite then click Installation Details to see the Eclipse.org Eclipse Platform version) https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider (seemed ok to Eclipse 4.9 and Java 1.6 only). So Subclipse seems the current way to go. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This depends.  [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) has superior support for checking out projects as maven projects - this is the sole reason we use Subclipse.  Other than that, I have noticed subclipse bugs with syncing with SVN.

[Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) is much better at detecting new files to add to version control, and is also far superior with merging code from a branch, or even syncing with SVN (fewer bugs, etc.).  So really, you should ask yourself what value you want.  If you're not using maven, I would definitely go for Subversive.

Comment: I'll go with Subversive. (I'm not using Maven). Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Is there any problem while using subversive with maven (2) ?

Comment: The only problem is with checking out SVN folder structures as maven projects.  This was a multi-step process when I last tried it (at least 6 months ago now).  Newer versions may have fixed this.

Answer (score 11):

I've recently switched from subclipse to subversive.  After upgrading our repository from v1.4.x to 1.5, we started having lots of issues with subclipse.

After doing a synch, you'd see updates that you had just accepted, and you wouldn't be able to take other updates without doing "hacks"

So far subversive is pretty nice. it even seems a little faster for lots of small files than subclipse was.

Answer (score 1):

I'm casting my vote for [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). I've had better luck with it than [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) personally.

Comment: Ha! First person to notice in nearly a year. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i use subversive. It has better usability features, mainly intuitive keyboard shortcuts etc.

I have never had a problem using either though. It really is just a combination of personal preference and usage though, if you're using advanced complex features it might matter which one you choose, but if your just checking in, checking out and synchronizing they will both meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

subclipse is fully packed with features, I have never had an issue with it.