# What is a good SVN plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

A few years ago I've installed several SVN plugins for eclipse. At the time I wasn't impressed with their quality. Many were slow, buggy and couldn't cope with any file interactions that didn't go through the plugin. So I went back to just using TortoiseSVN for windows and command line for linux. Now I'm ready to give it another try.

Which Subversion plugins for Eclipse are most popular currently and work well, how do they compare?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185486/which-eclipse-subversion-plugin-should-i-use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is the most popular, but [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) is the most usable IMO. Subversive was built to cleanly integrate into the Eclipse team system - something which Subclipse does't do that good. You can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320/svn-plugins-for-eclipse-subclipse-vs-subversive) for a discussion of both plugins.

Answer (score 4):

Subversive is meant to be the official eclipse svn plugin, but the setup was still more difficult than subclipse last time I installed.

Subversive does offer a richer interface, and I prefer it now over subclipse, even with the more complicated installation.

Answer (score 2):

While subclipse is a good plugin. It seems that [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) now has the upper hand. subversive is now part of the eclipse incubation process, and is planned to become the official subversion team provider for eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Subclipse has a very good integration with maven projects.  It's easy to use and intuitive. Despite of some minor bugs I have no complains after using it for several years.

Answer (score 1):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) is part of the Eclipse project now.