# Source control for a small project with few developers

Tags: java, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Source control system for single developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400/source-control-system-for-single-developer)

Hi,

I'm planning a small Java project for internal use that probably won't be released to the general public (at least not anytime soon). Being the sole developer, I'm inclined to start with a local project due to the simplicity & speed. However, i foresee at least a couple of developers joining in the near future so a source control system is needed.

It's at most a 5 person project.

Here are the main factors:

- Has to have a good integration into Eclipse (either stock or with a plug-in)
- Has to have a gradual learning curve
- Easy to view changes to source files
- Easy/intuitive merging/conflict resolution
- Not be a pain in the ass to use, meaning not to interrupt the regular development flow too much with its problems (check-ins/check-outs/transport/syncs/whatever)

What kind of source control do you recommend and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Source control system for single developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400/source-control-system-for-single-developer) and many, many others

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind your project being visible from the beginning, I'd recommend Git and [Github](http://github.com).  Git is easy to pick up and can do some advanced stuff when you get used to using it.  Github is a great way to collaborate with a team.  Also, Github does private repositories for a monthly fee.

If you want to do something local, then Git or SVN will work fine.  Both have eclipse plugins. I like [Subclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/subclipse/) for Subversion and Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Subversion (SVN). I've found it pretty easy to setup and use. If you want Eclipse integration, use the [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I know many can say that CVS is outdated and many alternatives like SVN, Git exists - but in my opinion Eclipse has really got great CVS client by default, which makes code management really easy. I have also tried and using EGit in Eclipse, but it lacks many of features what CVS client has. Disadvantage is that CSV requires some remote repository. This can be avoided by using, for example, Git/EGit.

It really is more related to what version control plugin features you need to have and planing to use in Eclipse.